# ¿Se puede mejorar este código de un listado con filtros? Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Lo que intenté hacer es lo siguiente:

- Si el usuario es "Admin" muestro todas las plantas.
- Si el usuario es "User1" muestro únicamente su planta.
- Si no se ha selecciona ningún área, selecciono la "0", la cual pertenece a la opción "All Areas" de mi formulario.
- Si se ha seleccionado "All Areas", cogo todas las áreas de la planta seleccionada y luego todos los equipos de esas áreas.
- Es obligatorio seleccionar una planta (no existe la opción "0", es decir, "All Plants").

¿Se puede mejorar este código? a simple vista no me parece muy profesional, me gustaría que me den consejos para poder aprender.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
         $plant = Plant::query();
         $areas = Area::query();
         $areas_id = [];
         $area_id = 0;
         $plant_id = 0;
         $equipment;

         if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
           $plant_id = (!empty($request->plant_id))? $request->plant_id: $plant->get()->first()->id;
           $area_id = (!empty($request->area_id))? $request->area_id: 0;
         }
         elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('user1')){
           $plant_id = Auth::user()->plant->id;
           $area_id = (!empty($request->area_id))? $request->area_id: 0;
         }

       if(!empty($plant_id)){
            $areas_id = DB::table('areas')->select('id')->where('plant_id', $plant_id)->get();
            $areas_id = json_decode(json_encode($areas_id), true);
       }

        //Lleno los select de mi formulario
         $plants = Plant::get();
         $areas = $areas->where('plant_id', $plant_id)->get();
         if(Auth::user()->hasRole('user1')){
            $plants = Plant::where('id', Auth::user()->plant->id);
         }
        if($area_id <> 0)
            $equipment = DB::table('equipment')->whereIn('area_id', $areas_id)->paginate(10);
        else
            $equipment = Equipment::latest()->paginate(10);
        return view('equipment.index', compact('equipment', 'areas', 'plants', 'plant_id', 'area_id'));
    }
```

Comment: Puedes probar con Scope, simplifica mucho el código principal y todas las consultas las haces desde el Modelo

Answer (score 1):

Para comenzar, prueba utilizando [relaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) y [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) para hacer tus consultas/queries. Por ejemplo:

- Una `Plant` tiene muchas `Area`s
- Un `Area` tiene muchos `Equipment`s

Por tanto tus modelos quedan de la siguiente forma:

**Plant.php**

```
use App\Area;

public function areas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Area::class);
}
```

**Area.php**

```
use App\Plant;
use App\Equipment;

public function plant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Plant::class);
}

public function equipments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Plant::class);
}
```

**Equipment.php**

```
use App\Area;

public function area()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
}
```

Ahora pasemos a la parte de las consultas. Respecto a lo que mencionaste:

> Si el usuario es "Admin" muestro todas las plantas , si el usuario es "User1" muestro únicamente su planta.

Esto es una [consultas condicionales](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses),

```
$plants = Plant
       ::when( ! auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'), function ($query) {
           return $query->where('id', auth()->user()->plant->id);
       });
       ->get();
```

PD1: Acá no estoy filtrando por "user_1" pues asumo que es el rol más bajo, pero si no es así puedes simplemente añadir otro filtro como tercer argumento de la función, que es lo que se ejecutaría si el primer argumento es falso.

> Si no se ha selecciona ningún área, selecciono la "0", la cual pertenece a la opción "All Areas" de mi formulario. Si se ha seleccionado "All Areas", cojo todas las áreas de la planta seleccionada y luego todos los equipos de esas áreas.

Puedes hacer esto cargando las `Area`s y `Equipment`s relacionados en cada `Plant` por medio de [cargar tempranas condicionadas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). Acá voy a condicionar los elementos hijos si es que hay algún `area_id` en el request:

```
$plants = Plant
    ::with(
        [
            'areas' => function ($query) {
                if ($id = request('area_id'))
                {
                    $query->where('id', $id);
                }
            },
            'areas.equipments' => function ($query) {
                if ($id = request('area_id'))
                {
                    $query->where('area_id', $id);
                }
            }
        ])
    ->get();
```

Que juntando todo en una sola consulta sería:

**MyCoolController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $plants = Plant
        ::with(
            [
                'areas' => function ($query) {
                    if ($id = request('area_id'))
                    {
                        $query->where('id', $id);
                    }
                },
                'areas.equipments' => function ($query) {
                    if ($id = request('area_id'))
                    {
                        $query->where('area_id', $id);
                    }
                }
            ]
        )   
        ->when( ! auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'), function ($query) {
            return $query->where('id', auth()->user()->plant->id);
        });
        ->get();

    return view('equipment.index')->with('plants', $plants);
}
```

Con esto tendrías una collección de `Plant`s, cada una de ellas con un atributo `areas` --que contendrá todas las áreas si es que no se especificó una en particular, y cada una de estas áreas incluirá un attributo `equipments` donde estarás todos los equipos vinculados a ese área.

PD2: Esta solución no toma en cuenta la paginación, pero en un formulario con multiples listas, no le veo mucho sentido pues no se sabría sobre qué paginar (?).

Pero claro, esto se ve no tan bonito y agranda el controlador.. por lo que puedes hacer uso de [local query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) y extraer esta lógica en el modelo para luego aplicarlos en el controlador:

**Plant.php**

```
public function queryLimitByRole($query)
{
   $query->when( ! auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'), function ($query) {
       return $query->where('id', auth()->user()->plant->id);
   });
}

public function queryWithAreasAndEquipments($query, $area_id)
{
    $query->with(
        [
            'areas' => function ($query) {
                if ($id = request('area_id'))
                {
                    $query->where('id', $id);
                }
            },
            'areas.equipments' => function ($query) {
                if ($id = request('area_id'))
                {
                    $query->where('area_id', $id);
                }
            }
        ]
    )
}
```

Entonces tu controlador se reduciría considerablemente a lo siguiente:

**MyCoolController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $plants = Plant
        ::limitByRole()
        ->withAreasAndEquipments(request('area_id'))
        ->get();

    return view('equipment.index')->with('plants', $plants);
}
```

---

PD3: Probablemente se me haya pasado una cosa u otra pues no lo he testeado, pero al menos te servirá como base para mejorar tu código.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte la molestia de escribir todo esto. Mi sistema tiene tres tipos de usuarios: Administrador, Usuario 1, Usuario 2. (En este caso, tanto Usuario 1 como Usuario 2 pueden ver lo mismo, así que supongo que lo dejaré tal cual). Con respecto a la paginación, si es necesaria ¿cómo la hago?. El único listado que tengo es de "equipos" los otros son "select" (listas desplegables)

Comment: Podrías definir los scopes (modificandolos, claro está) en el modelo `Equipment` y ahí sí podrías páginar los resultados a devolver.